# В админке WordPress после обновления не закрывается окошко

Tags: wordpress, cms

После обновления WP до версии 4.9.6–ru_RU появилось окошко, которое дико бесит, ибо оно не закрывается... В консоли браузера присутствуют ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю, что нужно исправить ошибки в консоли, но никто админку не трогал и тут такое... может кто встречался с этим багом?

Comment: Никто не в встречался. Это не в WordPress баг, а у вас. Ваши чудесные плагины или тема плодят ошибки в js, отчего он падает, и уже нечем закрывать окно. Отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную - и окно закроется.

Comment: [61 метр](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/d1rpgy/https://vrpark.ru/)?! (про , микседконтент уже не говорю). Серьёзно проблема в окошке в админке?